# Ribbon editing option greyed out in Office Home and Student 2016

Tags: ms-office, upgrade, office-2016

I just installed MS Office Home & Student 2016 edition on my Mac. Bringing up one of my Office 2016 PC files shows the main button on the front sheet in edit mode (clicking it does not fire the underlying macro). I have no buttons in the ribbon that allow this to happen. What's worse, though, is discovering to my horror that I cannot enable developer mode in this version. There is no apparent upgrade path: to upgrade to 2019 or Office 365 means a new purchase.

Nothing in the documentation indicated that this was going to be a hobbled version of Office. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you for your consideration of my little conundrum.

An Update:

In case someone else is curious about this, I did get an answer from a very helpful Jim Gordon MVP on the Microsoft site. He said:

> Are you saying that you don't see the Developer tab of the Ribbon? If so, go to Excel > Preferences. I think there's a checkbox in 2016 on either the General tab or the View tab that you can check to turn the Developer tab so it displays.
>
> Controls being disabled can be caused by certain factors. One is that you have a subscription and it expired or is not activated for some reason. I don't think this is the case here, because I suspect you have some other kind of license for Office or you would most likely be using Excel 2019.
>
> Controls can be disabled if the file you're working on was saved in an old format or by a non-office application. For example, many features of Office are not available when the file is in old .xls file format. Even if it was saved in .xlsx file format by an app such as LibreOffice, features are disabled and the file opens in "compatibility mode." In all these cases you can get functionality restored by using File > Save As and saving using a current file format (.xlsx .xlst .xlsb .xlsm etc)

Very useful. I will get stuck into some rudimentary Excel 2016 Mac tutorials now as this is definitely not your grandfather's Excel (2003).